# Animate sine wave

Tags: uiview, drawrect, uianimation

i'm trying to animate a sine wave in a small frame, i have searched a lot on SO and on the web, but the only goal that I was able to reach it's draw a static sine wave that translate from one side to another side, but doens't want a translation i want an animation draw of the sinewave that repetedaly animate in a frame. Anyone can help me? this is what i do now:

Wave.h

```
@interface Wave : UIView

@end
```

Wave.m

```
@implementation Wave

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:192/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1] set];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
float width = rect.size.width;
const CGFloat amplitude = 30 / 4;
for(CGFloat x = 0; x < width; x += 0.5)
{
    CGFloat y = amplitude * sinf(2 * M_PI * (x / width) * 5) + 30;

    if(x == 0)
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, x, y);
    else
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x, y);
}

CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

then in a UIViewController i do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.wave = [[Wave alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-58, 205, 90, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:self.wave];

[self animateWave];
}

- (void)animateWave {
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
    self.wave.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(+self.wave.frame.size.width/2, 0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    self.wave.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
}];
}
```

but i doesn't want a translation, i want a continuous draw animation.

**EDIT:**

**I Have edit my question using the CADisplayLink suggest in the comment:**

//  MainView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "AnimationLayer.h"

@interface MainView : UIView
{
AnimationLayer *alayer;
}

@end
```

//  MainView.m

```
#import "MainView.h"

@implementation MainView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

}
return self;
}

- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
if ([self superview])
{

    alayer = [[AnimationLayer alloc] init];
    alayer.frame = self.frame;
    [self.layer addSublayer:alayer];

}
}

@end

//  AnimationLayer.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface AnimationLayer : CALayer
{
CADisplayLink *displayLink;
}

@end
```

//  AnimationLayer.m

```
#import "AnimationLayer.h"

static bool _running;

@implementation AnimationLayer

- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay)];
    [self setNeedsDisplayOnBoundsChange:YES];
}

return self;
}

static CGPoint lastPoint = {0, 0};

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
if (!_running)
{
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    _running = YES;
    return;
}

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
CGRect rect = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2);
CGContextSetLineJoin(ctx, kCGLineJoinRound);
float width = rect.size.width;
const CGFloat amplitude = 30 / 4;

CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
lastPoint.x += 0.5;
lastPoint.y = amplitude * sinf(2 * M_PI * (lastPoint.x / width) * 5) + 30;
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);

CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

if (lastPoint.x == rect.size.width)
{
    [displayLink invalidate];
    _running = NO;
}
}

@end
```

and using it in this way in a uiviecontroller:

```
MainView *view = [[MainView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[self.view addSubview:view];
```

now my problem is that the drawing code draw only a little little segment that move in a sine wave, but doesn't draw the line, only this little segment, this is all my code so you can try and see the problem, how i can fix it?

Comment: How about `CAShapeLayer` or `CADisplayLink`?

Comment: i have never use it, can you make an example please?

Comment: Perhaps you can start by looking at the documentation and programming guides and then I can answer your questions instead of explaining everything from the beginning

Comment: i have edit my question, using the CADisplayLink can you take a look please?

Answer (score 0):

Create an animatable `phase` property (by declaring it `@dynamic`), that your `drawRect:` method depends on; then animate the `phase` with an infinite `CABasicAnimation`.

[Here](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/) is a great starting point for custom animatable properties.